# Honest feedback on my company's logo?

Tags: logo, critique, marketing

Can I get some honest feedback about this logo? It's for an ISO (Independent Sales Organization – a third party payment processing company that is authorized to handle merchant accounts for businesses). **The initials of the company are PP**. Please, don't hold back.

[image]

[Click here for full resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW9Y4.jpg)

Comment: It says 'pd'. I had to read your description to know it was supposed to be 'pp'

Comment: Yeah, that's a PD all day long. Does not work.

Comment: There is probably a reason why companies usualy dont design their own logo.

Comment: I don't know if I'd want to style my brand as 'peepee' either...

Comment: @PieBie You mean you don't pronounce your username as "peebee"?? ;)

Comment: @ZachSaucier yes, but I'm just a silly person on the internet, not a brand that wants to sell people stuff

Answer (score 4):

It reads as "Pd" -- there's no aspect which would cause it to be read as "PP". That *might* be overcome if the company name is **always** present as well. Otherwise, it's Pd.

Even with the company name present, it will, in all probability, inspire thoughts such as -- "If the company name is Pxxxxx Pxxxxxx, why is their logo a pd?"

I find the spacing between the two glyphs rather odd. There seems to be no thought to any alignment of the glyphs - not even vertical centering. They seem to rather randomly be placed next to each other. There's no harmony, no visual fluidity to the mark. It's just two randomly placed glyphs in the center of a circle.

In addition, line weights are too thin.

[image]

At smaller sizes it breaks and gets lost.